# $_GET variable is query not working when passed

Tags: php, mysql

Im using the following to assign a value to a variable if the variable is passed via the URL:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $sortBy = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'mgap_ska_id';
}
```

here is where the variable is being passed:

```
$result = "SELECT mgap_ska_id, mgap_ska_id_name, SUM(DISTINCT mgap_growth) as growthtotal, SUM(DISTINCT mgap_recovery) as recovery FROM mgap_orders "
        . "WHERE account_manager_id = '" . $_SESSION['account_manager_id'] . "' GROUP BY mgap_ska_id ORDER BY '".$sortBy. "' ";
```

The process is working fine if the variable isnt being passed, but the variable in the query becomes unassigned when passed through the link like such:

```
<a href = "customer_view.php?sort=mgap_ska_id_name">
```

Can anyone see where my error is?

FYI Ive tried it in the query with and without the quotes.

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION:**

Here is how I solved the problem: O checked for both POST and GET:

```
 if (!empty($_GET) || !empty($_POST)) {
    $sortBy = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'mgap_ska_id';
}  else {
$sortBy = 'mgap_ska_id';    
}
```

Comment: How exactly is it not working?

Comment: It is becoming not assigned or not found when being passed.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_GET);` show?

Comment: You're not [properly escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) anything here, so this is destined to have some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You should be using a database interface that supports placeholders like `?` which you can bind data to.

Comment: John - it shows the variable being passed and assigned as required, I think the issue is how I have specified it in the query.

Comment: Why do you check $_POST. I would think you should check $_GET at the first line.

Comment: Passing through a URL requires GET

Comment: Clicking the hyperlink will not send anything through HTTP POST - therefore `$_POST` will always be empty from that link, and `$sortBy` won't be assigned to `$_GET['sort']` (unless it's defined as that by default somewhere we can't see from this example).

Comment: so how do assign sortBy a value if the user hasnt clicked on the link? It needs the have a default value for users that visit the page other than from the link. The link is an internal link on the same page, not external.

Comment: Without knowing what it is you're actually trying to do, why you've specified that you're only defining the sort order when there's HTTP POST data ... it's very hard to actually answer the question in a way that's likely to be helpful I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks so KUCH for the help everyone. I eventually checked n=both POST and GET and hat solved it. I posted the solution above.

Comment: @TechnoCripple have you tried my [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23811079/1880431)

Comment: @meda - I did, but I needed to check both POST and GET on that page. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TechnoCripple thats what `$_REQUEST` is for it will check either `GET` or `POST`

Comment: I see what you're saying; I made the edit and, yes, your solution worked perfectly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From OP's [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810564/get-variable-is-query-not-working-when-passed#comment36628678_23810759)

> The page needs to check for a POST because it can receive such from
>   another entry point, but the URL sending the variable is on the same
>   page.I have to check the URL for the existence of the variable. –

Then makes use of [`$_REQUEST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
```

this line is your problem. If user clicks the link it's a get request, means $_POST is empty.

Comment: The page needs to check for a POST because it can receive such from another entry point, but the URL sending the variable is on the same page.I have to check the URL for the existence of the variable.